# Reading a csv into hdfs with a time column won't work

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I want to read a csv with a time column into hadoop where the time column will be read in as a string.

I've tried creating the csv in textedit instead of creating it in intellij.
As well as escaping the colons in the time.

```
example data:
time
11:11:11

Some hadoop wrapper...
```

Expected: bleh = dataframe with values in data...

ActuaL: 
19/07/24 14:30:33 WARN CSVRelation: Dropping malformed line: 11:11:11

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection

However, reading in spark works...

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().
  appName("myapp").master("local").getOrCreate()

val bleh = spark.read.csv("mycsv")
```

Comment: Which spark version are you using

Comment: spark 2.1.2 version

Comment: I think my error may not be due to the space in the column, it might just be due to the time...11:11:11...

Comment: Can you post the whole data that you are using?  Actually the "11:11:11" I don't think is the problem I wasnt able to recreate it

Answer (score 0):

Try to first isolate the problem from the "hadoop wrapper" by running the simple test from Spark and just clone spark from github, and then create file and and add a test onto `CSVSuite.csv` where the other CSV loading is being done.  Then execute the test and you can see it works just fine with your test data. So we can isolate it then to a problem with the hadoop wrapper.

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/spark.git
cd spark
git checkout v2.1.2-rc4 
vi sql/core/src/test/resources/test-data/time.csv
```

then modify the file in vi by just hitting `I` and typing

```
time
11:11:11
```

Then just modify the CSVSuite file

```
vi sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVSuite.scala
```

by adding the text as one fo the many tests in that test suite

```
  test("simple-csv-test-#2") {
    val timeRows = spark
      .read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load(testFile(timeFile))
      .collect()
      .length

    assert(timeRows == 1)

  }
```

and then just run the build script

```
build/sbt "sql/testOnly org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVSuite -- -z simple-csv-test-#2"
```

so you can see the problem is not in Spark because this test passes every time